# HTTP File Repository

Tags: ftp, repository

I'm looking for a HTTP based file repository / web application to facilitate passing large files back and forth to clients. Something similar to http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/?f=intro but more server friendly and easier for our staff to maintain client accounts.
Features need include:

- Each client needs to have isolated access to only there own files.
- An easy web interface for our staff to create/delete client accounts.
- Files mapped to a domain accessible folder on the server

Originally we used to use an FTP server, but that proved too hard for some clients to cope with. Then we moved to HFS, but its not simple enough for our staff to manage.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look into [HTTP Commander](http://www.element-it.com/asp-net-explorer-browser/online-share/web-file-manager.aspx). You can easily use SSL for secure logins, it matches all of your criteria, it's highly scalable and very user friendly and easy to learn / administer.

Comment: Has potential. A little pricey for what it is, although it does have quite a few features.

Comment: I've deployed it with several clients and they all love it. Dev is very responsive and does a great job responding to inquiries.